# tcl catch: different -code and -level in caught result options when return code is TCL_RETURN

Tags: return, try-catch, tcl

Please take a look at the following code snippet:

```
set catch_r [catch {    
    return -code return -level 0 "something"    
    #return -code break -level 1 "something"
} result options]
puts "catch result: \n$catch_r"
puts result:
puts $result
puts options:
puts $options
```

the output is

```
catch result:
2
result:
something
options:
-code 0 -level 1
```

If I use the commented line `return -code break -level 1 "something"`, the output is

```
catch result:
2
result:
something
options:
-code 3 -level 1
```

I tried more `return -code -level`, such as `-code continue` or `-code error` with different `-level` numbers, and found that values of `-code` and `-level` in `options` are the same as `return -code -level` if it is NOT `return -code return`.

If it's `return -code return -level N`, `options` will be `-code 0 -level N+1`, not `-code 2 -level N`. Why `return -code return` is treated this way by `catch`? What's the meaning of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every kind of `return -code X` gives `TCL_RETURN` until it has gone through as many stack levels as the value of the `-level` options. Then it gives the `TCL_` code that corresponds to its `-code` value. For `-code return` that is `TCL_RETURN`, which means it will go through one more stack level and give `TCL_OK`. As you write, `return -code return -level N` is the same as `return -code ok -level N+1`<sup>1</sup>. That is by design.

Documentation:
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm)

<sup>1</sup> pseudocode: the command will not actually do level arithmetic.